# Formula errors in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets with the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AA3="","",MID((LEFT(AA3,LEN(AA3)-1)),FIND("|",AA3)+1,30)))
```

now this returns a number.

The weird thing is it works in 100% of the cases and returns the appropriate number, if however I try and calculate with this number in a few odd occasions the new formula fails, telling me the "number" is not a number.

Example:

```
(-121|102)  -121    102  -->the first is a combination which I then break apart into -121 and 102
```

Copy the formulas down and all work 100%.

I then carry on to process these numbers and on the odd occasion, the formula tells me the "102" is not a number.

Below a sample output:

```
    (-121|102)  -121    102     76.00
    (-238|139‎)  -238    139‎       #VALUE!
    (-297|52)   -297     52     395.73
    (-127|201)  -127    201     186.81
    (-186|149)  -186    149     336.89
    (-141|120)  -141    120     290.08
    (-106|97‎)   -106     97‎       #VALUE!
    (-238|139‎)  -238    139‎       #VALUE!
    (-297|52‎)   -297     52‎       #VALUE!
    (-160|221)  -160    221     290.06
    (-197|200)  -197    200     294.55
    (-238|139‎)  -238    139‎       #VALUE!
     (-19|10)    -19     10       #VALUE!
     (-21|22)    -21     22     323.83
```

Is there anything I can put in the formula that would force the output to be a number?

```
=IFERROR(IF(AA3="","",MID((LEFT(AA3,LEN(AA3)-1)),FIND("|",AA3)+1,30)))
```

Comment: I know that for example in Excel, you can specify the type of the field. So if you write "121" in a field, you could mark it as text, number, or whatever. Btw, is "(-121|102)" the content of a cell or what? I don't find the situation extremely clear, I think I understand most, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by "invisible" non-numeric characters in some of your cells. If you list the character codes of one of the invalid numbers, for example line 2 in your sample output, you will see that there is a fourth invisible character with code *8206* at the end of the text. You can use this formula to verify this fact (provided the cell is at position `AA2`):

```
=CODE(MID(AA2,FIND("|",AA2)+4,1))
```

You should be able to use regular expression replacement to get rid of the non-numerical characters, like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(/* some text */,"[^0-9]","")
```

A valid formula for extracting the second numerical value from one text cell based on your original formula would thus be:

```
=IF(AA2="","",REGEXREPLACE(MID(LEFT(AA2,LEN(AA2)-1),
                               FIND("|",AA2)+1,30),"[^0-9]",""))
```

However, I would recommend a more stable formulation for identifying the second value, based on the positions of both `|` and `)`:

```
MID(AA2,FIND("|",AA2)+1,FIND(")",AA2)-FIND("|",AA2)-1)
```

yielding the following resulting formula for sufficiently extracting the second numerical value from the text cell:

```
=IF(AA2="","",REGEXREPLACE(MID(AA2,FIND("|",AA2)+1,
                               FIND(")",AA2)-FIND("|",AA2)-1),"[^0-9]",""))
```